# Android date change scipt not working

Tags: android, date, datetime, sh

I wrote a simple script changing date. It works correctly when I enter the lines separately in ADB. When I sh the script in ADB It throws me error (epoch number with @ on the beggining) or change the date incorrectly (year 2018...). Here is the code:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
currentdate=$(busybox date +%s)
currentdate=$(($currentdate + 5400))
currentdate=$(busybox date -d @$currentdate +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")
date -s $currentdate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
currentdate=$(busybox date +%s)
currentdate=$((currentdate+5400))
date -s $(busybox date -s @$currentdate '+%Y%m%d.%H%M%S')
```